# ValueError: You cannot perform fine-tuning on purely quantized models

Tags: large-language-model, huggingface

When trying to finetune a falcon 7b model on some training data of mine I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: You cannot perform fine-tuning on purely quantized models. Please attach trainable adapters on top of the quantized model to correctly perform fine-tuning. Please see: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/peft for more details
```

For training I am trying to use Nvidia NDV2. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I actually already created the Loraconfig and adding it to the model.

````
config = LoraConfig(
    r=16,
    lora_alpha=32,
    target_modules=["query_key_value"],
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)

model = get_peft_model(model, config)
print_trainable_parameters(model)```
````